# Transfer data from SQS to Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to transfer the messages I get from SQS and send them over to Dynamodb? I've tried making a Lambda function using CloudWatch to trigger it every minute. I'm open to using any other services in AWS to complete this task. I'm sure there's a simple explanation to this that I'm just overlooking.

*Edit my code does not work, I'm looking for either a fix to my code or another solution to accomplish this.

**Edit got it working.

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const SQS = new AWS.SQS({ apiVersion: '2012-11-05' });
const Lambda = new AWS.Lambda({ apiVersion: '2015-03-31' });

const QUEUE_URL = 'SQS_URL';
const PROCESS_MESSAGE = 'process-message';
const DYNAMO_TABLE = 'TABLE_NAME';

function poll(functionName, callback) {
    const params = {
        QueueUrl: QUEUE_URL,
        MaxNumberOfMessages: 10,
        VisibilityTimeout: 10
    };

    // batch request messages
    SQS.receiveMessage(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        // parse each message
        data.Messages.forEach(parseSQSMessage);
    })
    .promise()
    .then(function(){
        return Lambda.invokeAsync({})
        .promise()
        .then(function(data){
            console.log('Recursion');
        })
    }
    )
    .then(function(){context.succeed()}).catch(function(err){context.fail(err, err.stack)});
}

// send each event in message to dynamoDB.
// remove message from queue
function parseSQSMessage(msg, index, array) {

    // delete SQS message
    var params = {
      QueueUrl: QUEUE_URL,
      ReceiptHandle: msg.ReceiptHandle
    };

    SQS.deleteMessage(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
}

// store atomic event JSON directly to dynamoDB
function storeEvent(event) {
    var params = {
      TableName : DYNAMO_TABLE,
      Item: event
    };

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log(data);
    });
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        // invoked by schedule
        poll(context.functionName, callback);
    } catch (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: Related github project with an AWS Lambda function written in node that pulls messages from SQS and saves to DynamoDB: https://github.com/leaflevellabs/aws-lambda-sqs-dynamodb.

Comment: Does your code not work? Are you getting an error message? What's your question -- are you asking whether it's possible, or why your code does/doesn't work? Feel free to Edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var aws = require( "aws-sdk" );


// get configuration defaults from config file.
var tableName = 'Table_Name';
var queueUrl = 'SQS_URL';

var dbClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var sqsClient = new aws.SQS();



// get config values from dynamodb - if the config values are found, then override existing values
// this will occur on every execution of the lambda which will allow real time configuration changes.
var updateConfig = function updateConfigValues(invokedFunction, cb) {

    var params = { 
            TableName: "Table_NAME",

        Key: {
            "KEY": "KEY"
        }

    };

    dbClient.get(params, function(err, data) {

        if(err) {
            console.log("ERR_DYNAMODB_GET", err, params);
        }
        else if(!data || !data.Item) {
            console.log("INFO_DYNAMODB_NOCONFIG", params);
        }
        else {
            queueUrl = data.Item.config.queueUrl;
            tableName = data.Item.config.tableName;
        }

        return cb(err);
    });

};

// save the email to dynamodb using conditional write to ignore addresses already in the db
var saveEmail = function saveEmail(messageBody, cb) {


    var params = {
        TableName:tableName,
        Item:messageBody,
        ConditionExpression : "attribute_not_exists(clickId)",
    };

    dbClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
        cb(err, data);
    });
};

var deleteMessage = function deleteMessage(receiptHandle, cb) {

    var params = {
        QueueUrl: queueUrl,
        ReceiptHandle: receiptHandle
    };

    sqsClient.deleteMessage(params, function(err, data) {
        cb(err, data);
    });

}

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    updateConfig(context.invokedFunctionArn, function(err) {

        if(err) {
            context.done(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log("INFO_LAMBDA_EVENT", event);
        console.log("INFO_LAMBDA_CONTEXT", context);

        sqsClient.receiveMessage({MaxNumberOfMessages:10 , QueueUrl: queueUrl}, function(err, data) {

            if(err) {
                console.log("ERR_SQS_RECEIVEMESSAGE", err);
                context.done(null);
            }
            else {

                if (data && data.Messages) {


                    console.log("INFO_SQS_RESULT", " message received");

                        var message = JSON.parse(data.Messages[0].Body);

                        var messageBody = message.Message;

                        messageBody = JSON.parse(messageBody);




                        //  loops though the messages and replaces any empty strings with "N/A"
                        messageBody.forEach((item) => {
                            var item = item;
                            var custom = item.customVariables;
                            for (i = 0; i < custom.length; i++) { 
                                if(custom[i] === ''){
                                    custom[i] = 'N/A';
                                }
                                item.customVariables = custom;
                            }
                            for(variable in item) {

                                if(item[variable] === ""){
                                    item[variable] = "N/A";
                                    console.log(item);
                                }
                            }

                            var messageBody = item;
                        });
                        var messageBody = messageBody[0];
                        // Logs out the new messageBody
                        console.log("FIXED - ", messageBody);

                        // Checks for errors and delets from que after sent
                        saveEmail(messageBody, function(err, data) {

                            if (err && err.code && err.code === "ConditionalCheckFailedException") {
                                console.error("INFO_DYNAMODB_SAVE", messageBody + " already subscribed");
                                deleteMessage(message.MessageId, function(err) {
                                    if(!err) {
                                        console.error("INFO_SQS_MESSAGE_DELETE", "receipt handle: " + message.MessageId, "successful");
                                    } else {
                                        console.error("ERR_SQS_MESSAGE_DELETE", "receipt handle: " + message.MessageId, err);
                                    }
                                    context.done(err);
                                });

                            }
                            else if (err) {
                                console.error("ERR_DYNAMODB_SAVE", "receipt handle: " + message.MessageId, err);
                                context.done(err);
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log("INFO_DYNAMODB_SAVE", "email_saved", "receipt handle: " + message.MessageId, messageBody.Message);
                                deleteMessage(message.MessageId, function(err) {
                                    if(!err) {
                                        console.error("INFO_SQS_MESSAGE_DELETE", "receipt handle: " + message.MessageId, "successful");
                                    } else {
                                        console.error("ERR_SQS_MESSAGE_DELETE", "receipt handle: " + message.MessageId, err);
                                    }
                                    context.done(err);
                                });
                            }


                        });
                } else {
                    console.log("INFO_SQS_RESULT", "0 messages received");
                    context.done(null);
                }
            }
        });
    });

}
```